# Boost::regex issue, Matching an HTML span element

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I don't get it. I created this regular expression:

```
<span class="copy[Green|Red].*>[\s]*(.*)[\s]*<\/span>
```

to match certain parts of HTML code (a part between spans). For instance the following:

```
<span class="copyGreen">0.12</span>
<span class="copyRed">  0.12  </span>
```

Now, this works beautifully with RegexBuddy and others, but with Boost::regex
I have an issue. It doesn't match up.

EDIT: To be more precise, I want to capture the number between the spans. Before and after
the number, there can be white spaces as well (\n, \r, etc.).

Here's the code I've been done:

```
try {
        const boost::regex e("<span class=\"copy[Green|Red].*>[\\s]*(.*)[\\s]*<\\/span>");
        boost::smatch matches;
        std::string html("<span class=\"copyGreen\">  0.12  </span>");

        if (boost::regex_match(html, matches, e)) {
                // Works... (not).
        } else {
                throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't match the regex against HTML-source!");
        }
} catch (boost::regex_error& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

It seems, that the correct expression would be

```
boost::regex("<span class=\"copy(?:Green|Red)[^>]*>\\s*(.*?)\\s*<\\/span>"); // Thanks chaos!.
```

This actually matches up with Boost. However, I needed to enable boost::match_extra
in order to get all the captures I needed. This was done by defining

```
BOOST_REGEX_MATCH_EXTRA
```

in boost\regex\user.hpp

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, this:

```
[Green|Red]
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  You want:

```
(?:Green|Red)
```

`[Green|Red]` is a character class made up of the letters `GRred|`, not a way of alternating between matches.  The way you've written it, it will match exactly one of those characters followed by any number of other characters.

This:

```
[\s]
```

is redundant and maybe hazardous (depending on interpretation it could be what's actually making your match not work).  It can be just

```
\s
```

In order for your second `\s` to work, the capturing expression probably needs to be

```
(.*?)
```

I also recommend making your first `.*` into `[^>]*`, to avoid the problem you'll get if you ever apply this to actual HTML documents, where it will suck in arbitrary amounts of HTML.

Comment: Umm.. shouldn't it match either copyGreen or copyRed? I don't think I've got it wrong.. Please explain a little bit further, what and why I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Square brackets represent a single character match. That is [green|red] is identical to [gren|d] - it will match g OR r OR e OR n OR | OR d. For strings, you want alternation, which needs to be grouped inside parentheses to prevent it applying to the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of problems with your regex.

First is this bit: `[Green|Red]`

which maches a set of characters, that set is **`G`**, **`r`**, **`e`**, **`n`**, **`|`**, **`R`** and **`d`**.

you need to do this using parenthises, like `(Green|Red)`.  now this matches either the string **`Green`** or **`Red`**.

EDIT: if you don't want this to capture anything, you can use a non-capturing group, which in boost::regex is done by including a `?:` after the first parenthesis: `(?:Green|Red)`.  Now the regex has the grouping behavior of parentheses, but there is no capturing.

The second problem is the `(.*)`

This doesn't seem like much, but it matches too much, including patterns like consecutive spans. This will consume the end of one span and the start of the next, all the way to the last span on the page.  You need to make this non-greedy.  In boost::regex, you do that by following the `*` with a `?`. change it to look like `(.*?)` (and do similar with the other *'s.

The thing is, XML and HTML are very hard to get anything more than trivially simple regexes to work correctly.  You should really be using a library that is meant for working with that format.  There are plenty of [options](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+html+parser).  This way you can be sure that you are handling HTML correctly, no matter how contorted the input might be.

Comment: This really confuses me. Your suggestion, (Green|Red), captures either Green or Red. With that, I get two caputes now: Green and 0.12. I only want to get 0.12 between the spans.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Green|Red]
```

Is wrong because [] denotes a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in most regex syntaxes.  Character classes are basically groups of characters that can all be matched.  For example, [abc] will match "a", "b" or "c".

As for your other problems, there are a couple possibilities, such as TokenMacGuy mentions; (.*) could be matching too much.  In order to be sure, I'd need to see what exactly your regex is matching.

Finally, you really shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse HTML.  It gets to a pint where it just doesn't work except under the most controlled conditions and with way to complicated expressions.  It would be better to look into various html/xml parsers.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege) is a great explanation of why it's a bad idea.